# Creating a dynamic pivot table in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, data-structures, pivot-table

I'm trying to create a dynamic pivot table, the same as you can do in excel. However, it seems far more challenging then expected. I was able to create a non-dynamic pivot table, but the challenge for a dynamic pivot table lays for me in the unknown depth of an array. What you have to do to create a pivot table is group the row_ids belonging to one, or multiple answers.

Below there are three arrays. The first array shows the wished output. The second array shows the 'data' to be used. The third array shows how 'data' should be transformed into the output array.

The wished output array for this example can be seen directly below. For this example I have created only two depth levels of the array.The first numbers explained: 695 is an answer and 296 is an answer and 298 is a row_id.

**(first array Wished output)**

```
    (
    [695] => Array
        (
            [296] => Array
                (
                    [298] => 
                )

            [295] => Array
                (
                    [300] => 
                    [305] => 
                    [307] => 
                )

        )

    [696] => Array
        (
            [296] => Array
                (
                    [294] => 
                    [297] => 
                )

            [295] => Array
                (
                    [299] => 
                    [302] => 
                    [304] => 
                )

        )

    [697] => Array
        (
            [295] => Array
                (
                    [303] => 
                    [306] => 
                )

        )

)
```

Now I have two arrays below to get above result. The array below is the data input that needs to be transformed. First numbers in the array below explained, 120 is the column_id, 298 is the row_id and 695 is the answer_id

**(Second array) input**

```
Array
(
    [120] => Array
        (
            [298] => 695
            [300] => 695
            [305] => 695
            [307] => 695
            [294] => 696
            [297] => 696
            [299] => 696
            [302] => 696
            [304] => 696
            [303] => 697
            [306] => 697
        )

   
    [121] => Array
        (
            [294] => 296
            [297] => 296
            [298] => 296
            [299] => 295
            [300] => 295
            [302] => 295
            [303] => 295
            [304] => 295
            [305] => 295
            [306] => 295
            [307] => 295
        )

)
```

The array below is used to indicate how the array above needs to be converted into the wished output (first array). So the array below explained: on the first level of the array, answers out of column id 120 should be used. On the second level the answers of column id 121 should be used.

**(Third array) how input of second array can be transformed in wished output**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [array_level] => 1
            [column_id] => 120
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [array_level] => 2
            [column_id] => 121
        )

)
```

Any insights you might have are appreciated.

Comment: _“So the array below explained: on the first level of the array, answers out of column id 120 should be used. On the second level the answers of column id 121 should be used.”_ - are you confusing “levels” with “number of elements” here …?

Comment: @CBroe , I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. On the first level, the number of elements are equal to the number of unique elements in column id 120. On the second level the number of elements are equal to the number of unique answers in column_id 121 multiplied by number of elements in the first level of the array.

Comment: Unclear to me now, what exactly is supposed to be your input data, and what the actual expected result here. _“The wished array structure for this example can be seen directly below.”_ - is that meant to be input or output now? If the latter, then why are you saying _“The array below is used to indicate which structure the final array should have.”_ above that last array you have shown again then, that has a completely different structure than the first one? Please clarify.

Comment: @CBroe , appologies for the confusion. I have updated the question, explaining what each array is used for: "The first array shows the wished output. The second array shows the 'data' to be used. The third array shows how 'data' should be transformed into the output array."

Comment: So to get the 695 => 296 => 298 you want in the result, we have to check on the first level under 120 first. But there, the 695 is not connected to the 296 directly, but we now need to go look on the second level under 121, to find the 296 under key 298 there … trying to picture how this would look with an additional third or fourth level now. Sounds utterly complicated, and the whole thing seems kinda awkwardly backward. Where do you get this input data in this format _from_?

Comment: Yes, very complicated. I could give a different input structure if preferred. Above comes all from databases, but don't get me started on the structure of those. That will only complicate things

Comment: It’s hard to say what different input structure you could provide with reasonable effort though, when we don’t know what your data structure in the backgound is.